# Cannot send email using switch statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, parameters, nodemailer

I'm using node mailer to send out the emails and have followed a youtube tutorial, but I did some changes. I want to the user to send an email to any of the 31 people the he/she will choose, and so we will call the number assigned to people being chosen is classNum.

When I assign an email to the `to` parameter, the code works, but if I remove it and use the switch statement, it give the 500 error.

```
const sendMail = (email, subject, text,classNum, cb) => {
const mailOptions = {
  from: email,
  subject,
  text,
  to: " "
};
switch(classNum) {
  case 25:  
    mailOptions.to = 'thisIsAnEmail@gmail.com'          
    break;
}
```

This is probably the chunk of code that has a problem, please tell me if I need to add/post more code from the source code.

Comment: Well is it going into the switch? Seems like an easy thing to set a debugger and walk the code.

Comment: What does `mailOptions` look like after the switch statement? Are you certain it's not setting the `to` field properly? What about the `classNum` variable? What's that look like before it gets to the `switch` statement?

Comment: @epascarello it seems like it isn't going into the switch

Comment: Well what is `classNum`? `console.log(classNum, typeof classNum, classNum === 25);`

Comment: @daddygames The value inside  `to` and  `classNum` is the same after the switch statement.

Comment: @epascarello It said 25 string false

Comment: So you have a string, not a number

Comment: If you're getting an email address from a number (or string) why use a switch statement at all? Pull from an object or map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A switch expression uses [strict equality](http://Strict_equality)

With the debugging info I asked for in the comments, you are passing in a string and you are comparing it against a number. So `"25" === 25` is false.

You either need to make it a string

```
switch(classNum) {
  case "25":
```

or convert classNum to a number

```
switch(Number(classNum)) {
  case 25:
```

Answer (score 1):

As @epascarello indicated, you have a string in classNum, not a number; as a result, you "case" doesn't match.  You can fix this one of two ways:

1. Make sure classNum is a number, rather than a string (probably better, since classNum implies a number in the variable name) by using **classNum = Number(classNum)**; OR
2. change your switch case to be a string: **case '25':**

I think option 1 is probably better, again because the variable name implies a number value.